# Unable to upload files which are 4MB or more

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-3.5, fckeditor

I am trying to upload a file using my website.  Everything works file until the file which I am trying to upload is 4MB or more.

I have checked the IIS7.5 settings, and it seems to be set to 30MB upload size.  I am using FCKEditor to upload the files.

Does FCKEditor have a file upload limit?  If yes, how do I change it?  If no, why can't I upload files which are 4MB or more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase The default is 4096 (= 4 MB) `maxRequestLength` to 1 GB in web.config & 60000 seconds or whatever time you think it will take to upload

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="60000" />
</system.web>
```