# jQuery MVC5 File Upload :failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 500(internal server error)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, iis-7

I'm trying to upload an image using asp mvc as shown in this sample
https://github.com/CodeHeight/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC5

This sample is working properly with small images, but when file size exceeds 4 MB I get an error.

> failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 500(internal server error)

I've set

```
  <system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

and this

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="60000" />
</system.web>
```

but it doesn't work

Is there any setting or code that I must add?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to upload files which are 4MB or more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504009/unable-to-upload-files-which-are-4mb-or-more)

Comment: I would suggest Googling for `upload file greater than 4mb asp.net`.

Comment: Any luck trying the suggestions in the duplicate (and from the other Google links)?